# TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined - Slash Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a slash command for Avatar. I've used client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === avatarUser.id) to define USER, so it could show the users tag when executing the command. It shows the slash command in the server, but when I try to choose the person I want it to show the avatar to, it keeps giving me the error message shown in the title. Here is my code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    execute: async (interaction, client) => {

        let avatarUser = await interaction.options.getUser('user') || interaction.user

        const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === avatarUser.id)

        const name = user.tag

        const avatar = user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })

        const png = user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png' })
        const jpg = user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' })
        const gif = user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'gif' })

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${name}'s Avatar`)
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: 'Type',
                    value: `[PNG](${png}) [JPG](${jpg}) [GIF](${gif})`
                }
            )
            .setImage(avatar)
            .setColor('BLUE')

        interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you passing in the parameters in your *execution*? Is it as `interaction, client`?

Comment: @MrMythical yes, yes I have.

Comment: Can you show it please?